# Facebook - Open Graph Stories - predefined actions [mobile]

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So firstly, looking at the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph) I see:

> Custom Open Graph stories are deprecated in Graph API 2.8. Graph API
>   2.7 and lower will support custom Open Graph stories according to the following schedule:
>
> - Support for creating new objects will end in January 2017.
> - Support for publishing existing objects will end October 2017.

I want to achieve really simple thing: share a freshly created photo and a link to custom map provider at given coordinates. So I need to share the URL (of the map) and an Image.

Because I found it impossible with default components if the Facebook application is installed on the client device, I want to create an Open Graph Story for that. I need it to be the normal story, not custom one because the other one is going to be removed in the nearest time - as I quoted earlier.

Now there's a question: what in fact is a not custom action? The actions from [this Facebook action reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph)? If so, there are 10-15 actions and none of these is in any way matching my requirements! What can I do in such case..?

Comment: If there is no pre-defined action/object combination that matches your use case - then you simply can't use Open Graph stories.Letting the user post a link to your website that has the image set as thumbnail and shows the map there might be the alternative. Maybe mark the URL up as an Open Graph [`place`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/place/), if where the user is when publishing this is significant enough.

Comment: @CBroe I suspected there is no pre-defined pair for this use case. My website is a map service, it does not store the photos - just the maps. Like Google Maps. Can you write more about your last sentence? I don't understand this part.